# How to use resource properly

Tags: c++, qt, resources, qpixmap

When i use resorce it crash my program have no idea how to fix it. Name of resource Resource.grc, name of prefix /imag, name of picture srce_sedam_one.jpg. Everything else work fine.

```
QPixmap pixmap1 = QPixmap (":/imag/srce_sedam_one.jpg");
QMap<int, QPixmap> map;
map.insert(4, pixmap1);
ui->label_no->setPixmap(map.value(4));
```

Comment: where does it crash your program? What do you get when you run it inside a debugger?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `ui->label_no->setPixmap(map.value(4));` that is crashing? Are you calling this before or after `ui->setupUi(this);`?

Comment: calling before definitely

Comment: -1 because you didn't post the code that actually caused the problem. Minimal test cases: learn them, use them.\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in your pro-file and rebuild all.

```
RESOURCES += \
    icons.qrc
```

icons.qrc is in my case, you should use your filename. `Resource.qrc`

Then call after `ui->setupUi(this);`

```
ui->setupUi(this); 

QPixmap pixmap1 = QPixmap (":/imag/srce_sedam_one.jpg");
QMap<int, QPixmap> map;
map.insert(4, pixmap1);
ui->label_no->setPixmap(map.value(4));
```

You app crashes because:
    `ui->setupUi(this)` create all your widgets which you put in Qt Designer. And when you call `ui->label_no` before `setupUi`, you use null pointer and get crash.